# Perl Regular expression to read square bracket

Tags: regex, perl

I would like read bit inside square bracket and also want the square bracket.
The tricky part is class4.
`sample1[1]` is not a bit. Bit only at the end of line.

Example:

```
File1.txt
class1->Signal = sample1_sample2.sample3_sample4[4:4];
class2->Signal = sample1.sample2.sample3_sample4_sample5[2];
class3->Signal = sample1+sample2_sample3.sample4.sample5sample7[7:3];
class4->Signal = sample1[1]+sample2_sample3.sample4.sample5sample7[7:3];
```

Expectation result:

```
class1 bit = [1:2]
class2 bit = [2]
class3 bit = [7:3]
class4 bit = [7:3]
```

I use regular expression, but square bracket cannot be read.
`[] = Used for set of characters.`
`... = Any character except newline.`
ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-regex-cheat-sheet/

My CODE:

```
my $file = "$File1.txt";
my $line;

open (FILE,"<", $file) or die "Cannot open a file: $!";
while (<FILE>){
    my $line = $_;
    if ($line =~ m/[..]/){
        $line = $&;
    }
}
close (FILE);
```

Result only show:`.........`

I hope you guys can help me by giving idea. Thanks.

Comment: Try this one https://regex101.com/r/NEcKF4/1 With PCRE regex `^([^-]*)->.*?(\[[^]]*\]);` once and let me know how it goes. Cheers.

Comment: Is the square bracket always last before `;` as shown in examples?

Comment: @Destroy666 Yes. Square bracket contain bit always last before ```;```. But there will square bracket in middle of the words.

Comment: `perl -nE 'say "$1 bit = $2" if /(class\d+)->Signal.*(\[[:\d]+\])\s*;/' file.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[..]` makes a character literal for matching the characters within the brackets, period in this case.

Since you are only matching literal periods, this is all you see.

This problem can be solved with a fairly simple regex.

Since you only want the last bracket, you can rely on the greadiness of `.*` to skip any brackets in the middle:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "File1.txt"; 
my $line;

open (FILE, "<", $file) or die "Cannot open a file: $!";
while (<FILE>){
    $line = $_;
    if( $line =~ /(class\d).*(\[[^\]]*\]);/ ){
        $line = "$1 bit = $2";
    }
}
close (FILE);
```

the regex `/(class\d).*(\[[^\]]*\]);/` will match `class` followed by a digit, then the `.*` matches the rest of the line (hence it's greedy) and gives back enough to match `(\[[^\]]*\]);`

Using `^` as the first character in a character literal makes it match anything EXCEPT the characters within.
To match literal `[` you have to escape it like `\[`.

```
(              # capture to $1 
    class\d    # match "class" followed by a digit
)              # end capture
.*             # match anything (greedy)
(              # capture to $2
    \[         # literal [
    [^ \] ]*   # match anything, except ] (greedy)
    \]         # literal ]
)              # end capture
;              # match ;
```

The parentheses will save what is matched within to the variables `$1, $2, ...` etc.

This can also be done with substitute, using the same regex and the /r flag to return the value:

```perl
while (<FILE>){
    $line = s/(class\d).*(\[[^\]]*\]);/$1 bit = $2/r;
}
```

Here's a simple command line one-liner that'll do the same:

```bash
perl -wlp -e 's/(class\d).*(\[[^\]]*\]);/$1 bit = $2/' File1.txt
```

*change `'` to `"` to run on windows*

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples please try following regex in PCRE.

```
^([^-]*)->.*?(\[[^]]*\]);$
```

Here is the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/NEcKF4/1) for above regex.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
^            ##Matching from starting of the value here.
(            ##Creating 1st capturing group here.
  [^-]*      ##Matching everything before very next occurrence of - here.
)            ##Closing capturing group here.
->           ##Matching literal -> here.
.*?          ##Using lazy match to match till next occurrence of [ mentioned below.
(            ##Creating 2nd capturing group here.
  \[[^]]*    ##matching literal [ following by very first occurrence of ] here.
  \]         ##Matching literal ] here.
)            ##Closing 2nd capturing group here.
;$           ##Mentioning literal ; at the end of the value here.
```

Comment: Hey man, all is well? This `.*?` does not have to be non greedy as the last part of the pattern is already at the end of the string.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, with GOD'S grace on me I am ok, how are you. Yeah I know it's one and only occurrence but thought to use lazy match since its PCRE, cheers

Comment: Yes I agree that `.*?` should be just `.*` as you already have end anchor.

Answer (score 4):

You could select the part that you want to remove, and replace with  `bit =`

```
^[^-]*\K->.*(?=\[[^][]*\];$)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^-]*\K` Match optional chars other than `-` and forget what is matches so far using `\K`
- `->.*` Match `->` and the rest of the line
- `(?=\[[^][]*\];$)` Positive lookahead, assert `[...];` at the end of the line

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fF86H9/1) and a [Perl demo](https://tio.run/##lYxBC4IwGIbv36/YwUMaKupEcGUI3TrWbc6xQmqwRJzhIfrtpjhP0qHTs328z9NUrYqH4aUrpLtW3joC07sXbS3ruyYA/UOqCm12x/ySZza8ASHtl7R0mVOc3MxzNod9QWnJ6HhgxLJ9dJUd2iOfjNOmlXWHLE7gA8D5FOEcbkpoHbjZWd5rocatFs9GVQGfGXozI/PHFKeYkVkL15r3QzOMabjI0VreGtmMIxPBhvGMhCZptFTwukID9ldoGL4)

Example

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>)
{
  s/^[^-]*\K->.*(?=\[[^][]*\];$)/ bit = /;
  print $_;
}

__DATA__
class1->Signal = sample1_sample2.sample3_sample4[4:4];
class2->Signal = sample1.sample2.sample3_sample4_sample5[2];
class3->Signal = sample1+sample2_sample3.sample4.sample5sample7[7:3];
class4->Signal = sample1[1]+sample2_sample3.sample4.sample5sample7[7:3];
```

Output

```
class1 bit = [4:4];
class2 bit = [2];
class3 bit = [7:3];
class4 bit = [7:3];
```

---

Or a bit more specific regex:

```
^class\d+\K->.*(?=\[[^][]*\];$)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8hlZ2x/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /tmp/a.txt
class1->Signal = sample1_sample2.sample3_sample4[4:4];
class2->Signal = sample1.sample2.sample3_sample4_sample5[2];
class3->Signal = sample1+sample2_sample3.sample4.sample5sample7[7:3];
class4->Signal = sample1[1]+sample2_sample3.sample4.sample5sample7[7:3];
```

```
sed -e 's/->.*\[/ bit = [/g' -e 's/;//g'  /tmp/a.txt
class1 bit = [4:4]
class2 bit = [2]
class3 bit = [7:3]
class4 bit = [7:3]
```